# Docker - New contianer keeps using old user data

Tags: docker, docker-container, home-assistant

I am using docker to run Home Assistant container, The host machine is Ubuntu.

After running the container I uploaded a snapshot from my RPi to restore the data and it worked fine.

Now the problem is I want a fresh install of HA but every time I run the container(new run) I still keep getting the old user data from the initial container (the snapshot I uploaded).

I tried deleting the images, containers, volumes, and even the docker and container folders under var/lib, reinstalled docker but without any luck.

Here are the commands I used to install the container:

```sh
sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl gnupg-agent software-properties-common

curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add -

sudo add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs) stable"

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io

sudo apt install jq

sudo su

sudo curl -sL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/home-assistant/supervised-installer/master/installer.sh | bash -s

docker container ls -a
```

Comment: It seems that the container mounts a host directory, which is defined in a file called `hassio.json` under the key `.data` (see https://raw.githubusercontent.com/home-assistant/supervised-installer/master/installer.sh and https://raw.githubusercontent.com/home-assistant/supervised-installer/master/files/hassio-supervisor for reference). I would assume that we have to clear this directory. As to where the `hassio.json` is located: I am not entirely sure. It might be located at `/etc/hassio.json`.

Comment: Guess ill go with virtualization for now.